# Can I quit after 2 days due to allergy?

Tags: quitting, health

So I just landed my first proper job at a cafe yesterday, I was ecstatic. My job involved clean hands, so I had to wash them again every time my hands basically touched anything but food.

But today nearing the end of the day, my hands were beginning to redden. When I came home from work, the skin on the back of my hands started feeling tight and the redness was even more prominent. As I have almost grown out of my eczema, I am worried that in the long term, this necessity to sanitise hands will bring back my eczema or make it worse.

I want to quit tomorrow when I'm supposed to begin another work day. As my hands as they are now, are uncomfortable and redden all over again when under water.

Is my reason ok to quit after the 2nd day? Please advice.

Comment: Not the answer you were after but have you tried wearing hypoallergenic disposable gloves? They help my eczema.

Comment: Yes, it's a good reason to quit. But I would check on the soap they're using. I bet you're not the only one with this problem if you check on the internet.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was supposed to do hand over bank details yesterday for my wages but my manager left early so I haven't actually signed any contract or agreement.

Comment: If you quit and continue to work in the same industry, you might run into a similar problem in the future. Unless its something truly specific to that one cafe. It may behoove you to investigate countermeasures even if you do end up quitting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure many areas have food safety regulations that require you to wash your hands even if you wear sanitary gloves. Even if you don't have a skin condition, very frequent handwashing can and will irritate the skin.  There might be things you can do to mitigate, such a using moisturizing lotions, so I very much suggest consulting a dermatologist. If you cannot find a solution, it might still be best to avoid food industry work, however.

Answer (score 7):

A progressive answer:

- Are there gloves available that minimize/eliminate the problem?
- If not, do you know of any you can buy?

  - Will youre employer pay for them if you truly need them?

I'm not suggesting you make a scene, but rather you seek out a means to do your job without adverse effects to your personal health. A box of 100 "powdered" medical gloves is about $3.00. If you can get those, and they don't affect your job (ie: hope you're not kneading pizza dough, as that'd taste gross), and you're all set.

Let us know more about your situation.

Best of luck!

PS: You can quit whenever you want, but you aren't entitled to a reference beyond proof that you worked at a company for however many days, which is provided in the form of a record of employment (ROE). The only possible exception might be if you were working for some clandestine military agency.

**Edit**: You can quit whenever you want, but you would still be expected to provide your 2 weeks' notice, unless you have an at-will employment or probation period term in your employment agreement.

Comment: Powered gloves? I don't think that's a good idea, but other types of gloves may work.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk They're easy to remove if you have to alternate between cash and handing out bags of food, without handling food directly. I've known a number of people at McDonalds restaurants who've used them, even if they have to burn through 30/hour.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think she was planning to ask for a reference, or even list it on her resume. She'll have to go into an entire new line of work if she doesn't want the same thing to happen at a new job.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Right on both counts.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unless that coffee shop is Starbucks and provides a Medical plan for you to see a dermatologist, you may want to quit now.

This is perfectly understandable. Any coffee shop owner/manager would understand.

> What causes a hand rash? A hand rash, also called hand dermatitis or
> hand eczema, may be caused by many things. Hand rashes are extremely
> common. Many people start with dry, chapped hands that later become
> patchy, red, scaly, and inflamed. Numerous items can irritate skin.
> These include overexposure to water, too much dry air, soaps,
> detergents, solvents, cleaning agents, chemicals, rubber gloves, and
> even ingredients in skin and personal care products.
>
> **Once skin becomes
> red and dry, even so-called "harmless" things like water and baby
> products can irritate the rash, making it worse.** Your doctor will try
> to find out what substance in your everyday routine could be causing
> or contributing to the problem. Often your skin will get better by
> changing products or avoiding an ingredient completely. A tendency to
> get skin reactions is often inherited. People with these tendencies
> may have a history of hay fever and/or asthma. They may also have food
> allergies and a skin condition called atopic dermatitis or eczema.
> Their skin can turn red, and itch, indicating an allergy, after
> contact with many substances that might not bother other people's
> skin. Finding the Culprit Your dermatologist will work with you to
> uncover and identify the possible causes of a hand rash. Could it be
> irritation? Could it be an allergy? Like a detective, your
> dermatologist will ask many questions.
>
> [...]
>
> http://www.dermconsultants.com/general-dermatology/hand-eczema

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's definitely a good reason to quit. And you would never need permission to quit a job. That's the reason, why its called 'quit' also without giving prior notice. Just understand that it wouldn't be a great idea to add this particular job to your resume, considering you only been there for 2 days.

Good luck.